# Wrong XCode Project Location After Git Clone

Tags: ios, xcode, git, github

I'm pretty new to Git and Bitbucket etc so am hoping this is something easily fixed although after Googling around I can't find anything similar.

I have an XCode Workspace (project and pod stuff) which I have made a git repository for. I've then created a new remote repository on Bitbucket and pushed the local repository there. So far pretty simple.

I have then gone on to another machine and pulled the repository and here is where I get a problem. In the workspace I can see / expand the Pods but the project is showing with red text and is not expandable.

[image]

I had no idea at first why this was but I then noticed that if I left click on the project and look at the identity and type on the right hand side the location is wrong. The path in th epic below is not the path to the project file on the new computer. Instead it is the path to the file on the original computer which was used to push the repo up to Bitbucket.

[image]

I've tried changing the location but the best I can do is open the project rather than the Workspace. Ideally I'd be able to change the way it in the original so that the it doesn't need changing in clones but I can't seem to do this in a satisfactory way either.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How did you checkout this project? Using Xcode checkout?

Comment: Yes, I checked it out with XCode checkout. Is that not a good way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty common problem, usually met when passing projects around

**Solution**

Press the folder icon under 'Location' and choose the folder the contains your .xcodeproj

Comment: Thanks for the answer but when I do this, although the project name is now no longer red it still shows the .xcodeproj extension and more importantly is still not expandable

Comment: Also it might be worth mentioning that the "Full Path" shows the path to the folder I choose. It doesn't seem to pick out the .xcodeproj file inside the folder and put the path to that.

Comment: Then, can you try selecting the .xcodeproj file instead of the folder?

Comment: When I click on the little grey folder it only lets me chooses a folder. If I click on the little grey arrow below in the Full Path section it lets me choose the project file but instead of changing the file it closes my workspace and opens the project instead so I lose my pods.

Comment: Does the project open correctly if opened individually?

Comment: Yes. It seems that the project itself is fine.

Comment: I always solved this by selecting the folder, under 'Location'. Can you check project naming consistency? What's for sure is that Xcode is unable to load the .xcodeproj file.

Comment: What is project naming consistency? And how would I check it?

Comment: Under 'Identity and Type' there is project name (the one you grayed out), that should match the name of the '.xcodeproj' file on the disk, but if the project was ok on other machine I doubt that would be the problem.

Comment: Coming back to this much later - eventually it just ended up working ok! Not sure why but I've accepted this answer as it probably would be the correct one if only XCode wasn't such a buggy bloated whale